# system locale language settings

Tags: windows, system, locale

I set my system locale language under "Region and Language" options in the Control Panel to Chinese, however it changes the default language for many of my English-default programs as well.

However, the most annoying thing is that, as I am also a developer, it changes many things in my command prompt command line displays to Chinese as well.

Does anyone know of a way to only change certain programs to use the Chinese system locale?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: That's your user's locale, not the system locale, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13209)

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13209

[Additional procedure to install it in Vista or 7](http://www.mydigitallife.info/workaround-to-install-microsoft-applocale-utility-in-windows-vista/)

http://www.mydigitallife.info/workaround-to-install-microsoft-applocale-utility-in-windows-vista/